# Create Score with a skewed data

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, natural-language, bias

I'm trying to create a reputation score for sneakers using positive and negative sentiments of twitter on these sneakers (something like score = p+n). The problem is that the mean of positive != mean of negative sentiments so I don't know how to deal with it.

thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why should the positive mean equal the negative mean? What would you do if those values were equal?